# Sending 8 bytes to browser after making Websocket Connection 

Tags: javascript, c++, sockets, ubuntu, websocket

I have started to write a small `WebSocket Server` in C++. Im using `Ubuntu`. The server listens for incomming connections. Once a connection has been established, the browser sends the server a WebSocket header, including the `Sec-WebSocket-Key` which is hased with `SHA-1`, `base64 encoded` and then sent back to the browser as `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` with the rest of the header. This results in an open WebSocket connection between the browser and my server.

I have read the part of the specification on data framing and am trying to send data from my server to the browser. Below is my code:

```
cout << "sending data..." << endl;

uint8_t to_send[8];

to_send[0] = (uint8_t)129;  // 10000001
to_send[1] = (uint8_t)6;    // 00000110
to_send[2] = 'h';
to_send[3] = 'e';
to_send[4] = 'l';
to_send[5] = 'l';
to_send[6] = 'o';
to_send[7] = '\0';          // 00000000

int bytesSent = send(i, &to_send, 8, 0);
cout << "bytes sent: " << bytesSent << endl;
```

The 'fin' bit, three reserved bits and the opcode '0001' for text frames constitute the first byte. The second byte is the length of the text im sending - the string "hello" followed by a null escape character. My JavaScript code for debugging is:

```
ws.onopen = function()
{
    alert("WebSocket connection open");
}

ws.onmessage = function(event)
{
    alert("Data has been received");
}
```

After my server sends the 8 bytes i would expect an alert from the browser saying data has been received however this is not the case. I've tested on chrome and firefox.

Can anybody see where i'm going wrong?

Comment: buffering? setvbuf/setbuf to the rescue. Also, various socket options might apply to immediate writing

Comment: I haven't used that before? Could you provide an example?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with this part except I can't seem to remember anything about that '\0' character. Why is that being sent?

Comment: I have sent that to terminate the string, I didn't know if it was needed or not? After your comment I tried omitting it but the browser still didn't alert me that it had received a message..

Comment: @alexyoung91 just google the man pages. Or, use netcat or similar to see what your code is actually sending. Caveat: netcat is (normally) linebuffered. `stdbuf` might be able to help here, but I wouldn't be too sure

Comment: You don't need the terminating null; omit it and use length of 5. I'm concerned that the connection hasn't been established correctly: are you sure the browser actually has accepted the connection? The problem may be in your connection setup. Chrome devtools for example will show you this.

Comment: I get an alert saying "WebSocket connection open" as in the javascript alert. I wonder whether the data is getting sent. I am going to try the accessing the server from chrome on a different machine.

Comment: In chrome, after the WebSocket connection open message, the network has type: pending, time: pending - but isnt that something to do with the open connection and chrome still treating WebSocket connections as HTTP ones? I have also omitted the terminating null.

Comment: It'd be interesting to add alerts for onerror and onclose in your client as well.  If that doesn't give any hints, can you post your server code please?